# The trigonometric expression $\frac{1}{2}\sin x$ is equivalent to

Tags: trigonometry

The trigonometric expression $\frac{1}{2}\sin x$ is equivalent to?

Answer (score 1):

If you know the formula for $\sin(a+b)$, apply it to $\sin x = \sin\left(\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x}{2}\right)$.

Answer (score 1):

See that 
$$\sin{x}=2\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$$